# How to go about creating share cards (facebook, twitter) for a single page react application?

Tags: reactjs, twitter, metadata, single-page-application, facebook-opengraph

I'm developing an SPA in React and I've hit a wall that I'm not sure how to work around; I need different pages to display different information in share cards when shared on twitter and facebook (like how Pinterest uses whatever picture you're sharing as the thumbnail), but this is handled through metadata that React packages like React-Helmet have no effect on (since they load with the page). How should I approach this?

The only metatags that seem to have any effect on the share cards are the ones at the top of the singular "index.html" page that a common react SPA starts off with. I tried using React-Helmet to personalize my app's pages with the specific information I wanted, and while these metatags *do* load on the page itself, they have no effect on the share cards.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.